# Word that means "waste of life"

Tags: word-choice

So just, is there a word that means waste of life, whereby it is fitting in the context of war analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Surely, even if this is an expression, not a word:

[***Charge of the Light Brigade***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_of_the_Light_Brigade)

> The Charge of the Light Brigade was a charge of British light cavalry
>   led by Lord Cardigan against Russian forces during the Battle of
>   Balaclava on 25 October 1854 in the Crimean War. Lord Raglan, overall
>   commander of the British forces, had intended to send the Light
>   Brigade to pursue and harry a retreating Russian artillery battery, a
>   task well-suited to light cavalry. Due to miscommunication in the
>   chain of command, the Light Brigade was instead sent on a frontal
>   assault against a different artillery battery, one well-prepared with
>   excellent fields of defensive fire.
>
> Although the Light Brigade reached the battery under withering direct
>   fire and scattered some of the gunners, the badly mauled brigade was
>   forced to retreat immediately. Thus, **the assault ended with very high
>   British casualties and no decisive gains.**
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_of_the_Light_Brigade)

Perhaps

[***a Passchendaele***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Passchendaele)

> Vanier: soldier, diplomat and governor general: a biography - Page 64
>   Robert Speaight - 1970
>
> **Passchendaele** became **a synonym for the waste of life on the western front**, and when the 'Van Doos' relieved one of the forward
>   units it lost ninety officers and men, either killed or wounded.